# counting duplicates in a text file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file of the following type:

```
XLOC_000001 - - TCONS_00000001 - TSS1 
XLOC_000002 - - TCONS_00000002 - TSS2 
XLOC_000003 - - TCONS_00000003 - TSS3 
XLOC_000003 - - TCONS_00000004 - TSS3 
XLOC_000004 - - TCONS_00000007 - TSS4 
XLOC_000004 - - TCONS_00000008 - TSS4 
XLOC_000004 - - TCONS_00000009 - TSS4 
XLOC_000004 - - TCONS_00000010 - TSS4 
XLOC_000004 - - TCONS_00000011 - TSS4
```

And I want to count the number of duplicated ids in the first column and also print the other columns in the following way:

```
1 XLOC_000001 - - TCONS_00000001 - TSS1 
1 XLOC_000002 - - TCONS_00000002 - TSS2 
2 XLOC_000003 - - TCONS_00000003 - TSS3 
              - - TCONS_00000004 - TSS3 
5 XLOC_000004 - - TCONS_00000007 - TSS4 
              - - TCONS_00000008 - TSS4 
              - - TCONS_00000009 - TSS4 
              - - TCONS_00000010 - TSS4 
              - - TCONS_00000011 - TSS4
```

I used awk and tried this

```
 awk '{h[$1]++}; END { for(k in h) print k, h[k] }' newtrails.txt
```

This only gives the count of the first column but could anyone please edit the code to print other columns as shown above?

Comment: Are these duplicates always consecutive?  Could `XLOC_000003` re-appear and is the count reset to zero at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, `gsub()` can be your best friend:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]++; next} seen[$1]++{gsub(/./," ",$1)} {print ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : FS,$0}' file file
1 XLOC_000001 - - TCONS_00000001 - TSS1 
1 XLOC_000002 - - TCONS_00000002 - TSS2 
2 XLOC_000003 - - TCONS_00000003 - TSS3 
              - - TCONS_00000004 - TSS3
5 XLOC_000004 - - TCONS_00000007 - TSS4 
              - - TCONS_00000008 - TSS4
              - - TCONS_00000009 - TSS4
              - - TCONS_00000010 - TSS4
              - - TCONS_00000011 - TSS4
```

This reads the file twice:

- Firstly to count how many times the first column appears.
- Then, to print the values. It prints the 1st column just the first time; otherwise, it replaces all its characters with spaces. Then, the line is printed.